# Why can't I run update-manager-d to upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I'm semi-new and not an idiot with computers.  I can't get update-manager-d to run and it says that their is no such thing.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `update-manager -d` (note the space).  `update-manager` is the name of the program, `d` is an option flag.

You indicate options with a dash (`update-manager -d`) when they are a single letter (which most are), and you indicate them with a double dash (`update-manager --devel-release`) when they are a word.  Often, both forms are available for common options for a program.  Run `man <program-name>` for more details on the program's available options.